# `contenteditable = true` height issue in FireFox

Tags: html, css, firefox, contenteditable

When there is an empty `div` with `contenteditable="true"`:

CSS:

```
[contenteditable="true"] {
    border: 1px dashed #dedede;
    padding: 3px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div contenteditable="true">
    <!-- blank by default -->
</div>
```

In IE and Chrome, it shows the height like a normal input field with small padding. In Firefox, it only shows that 3px padding I added in the styles.  W/o that, it collapses and is only as tall as the border.

Do you know if this is a Firefox bug? Can you suggest a way to handle it?

Comment: You are probably relying on browsers' default styles, that's why you see the differences. Try using a CSS reset and applying your styles. http://www.cssreset.com/

Comment: I've only seen this issue in Firefox.

Comment: See also https://github.com/w3c/editing/issues/70

Answer (score 22, accepted):

workaround:

```
[contenteditable='true']:before {
    content: "\feff ";
}
```

[CSS2 section 10.6.3](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#normal-block):

> The element's height is the distance from its top content edge to the first applicable of the following:
>
> 1. the bottom edge of the last line box, if the box establishes a inline formatting context with one or more lines
> 2. the bottom edge of the bottom (possibly collapsed) margin of its last in-flow child, if the child's bottom margin does not collapse with the element's bottom margin
> 3. the bottom border edge of the last in-flow child whose top margin doesn't collapse with the element's bottom margin
> 4. zero, otherwise

For this empty div,

1 through 3 are not applicable, since the div is empty. It has no line boxes or children.
Item 4 therefore applies.

The workaround enforces at least one line box inside the div, so that it gets nonzero height.

Comment: For those, like me, who are looking for a special unit to use with CSS `min-height` that indicates the line-height, [there isn't such a unit ATM](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1098151#c18).

Answer (score 0):

This works just fine for me in firefox

http://jsfiddle.net/D6D6A/

html:

```
<div contenteditable='true'></div>
```

css : *changed to black border so easier to see*

```
[contenteditable='true'] {
    border: 1px dashed #000;
    padding: 3px;
}
```

notice if you change padding to 0px , it has no height. However, with the 3px padding, it works like it should.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Unfortunately, in Firefox v28.0 for Windows (what I am testing on) , the fiddle you posted as the same results as I mentioned in my question.

Comment: This has the same issue on Firefox -- the height collapses.