# How to make empty contenteditable spans keep their height

Tags: html, css, contenteditable

I have an editable span element that will be initially empty. Its height varies when it's empty and when its not, and can't figure out how to make give it the correct height.

```
<b>Foo:</b> <span contenteditable>Bar</span>-<span contenteditable></span>

span[contenteditable]
{
    display: inline-block;
    min-width: 2ch;
    height: 1em;
    padding: 0 .2em;
    outline: 1px solid @text-subtle-color;
}
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: in which browser you see this ? it's fine on chrome for me

Comment: @TemaniAfif just checked, seems to be yet another Firefox issue with "inputs"...

Comment: @TemaniAfif Hm, interesting. Does here too, in both Chrome, IE *and* Edge. The issue seems to be happening only in FireFox. 

Answer (score 4):

As noted by @temani-afif and @facundo-corradini, this issue seems to be an inssue only in FireFox. With a couple more searches with that in the query I found [a simple fix](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23530317/39321) that seems to work, and also not mess anything up in the other browsers:

```
*[contenteditable]:empty:before
{
    content: "\feff"; /* ZERO WIDTH NO-BREAK SPACE */
}
```

**Note:** If I drop the `:empty` selector, which was not part of the linked answer nor [the answer of @facundo-corradini](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48260736/39321) here, things looks off again. Their extra  does also not seem to make a difference.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with the ***Flexbox***:

```css
.flex-container {
  display: inline-flex; /* takes only the content's width */
  /*align-items: stretch; by default / takes care of the equal height among all flex-items (children) */
}

.flex-container > * {
  margin: 0 5px; /* just for demonstration */
}

span[contenteditable] {
  /*display: inline-block;*/
  min-width: 2ch;
  /*height: 1em;*/
  /*padding: 0 .2em;*/
  /*outline: 1px solid @text-subtle-color;*/
  border: 1px solid; /* also this */
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <b>Foo:</b> <span contenteditable>Bar</span>-<span contenteditable></span>
</div>
<div class="flex-container">
  <b>Foo:</b> <span contenteditable>Bar</span>-<span contenteditable>123</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's an issue with empty content editable specifically on Firefox.

A workaround is to set a pseudo-element containing a *zero width no-break space* "character" as follows:

```css
span[contenteditable]
{
    display: inline-block;
    min-width: 2ch;
    height: 1em;
    padding: 0 .2em;
    outline: 1px solid grey;
    box-sizing:border-box;
  content="";
}

span[contenteditable]:before {
    content: "\feff ";
}
```

```html
<b>Foo:</b> <span contenteditable>Bar</span>-<span contenteditable placeholder=""> </span>
```